# cannot echo data in a file located in extension/bootstraps/widgets

Tags: yii

I am using Yii 1.1 .I have a class file inside widgets folder named MyCommentsTbEditableSaver.
when i try to echo data with in that php file .it doesnot return any thing.
What is the reason behind this?
my code:`

```
public function insertRps()
{
    //get params from request
    $this->primaryKey = yii::app()->request->getParam('pk');
    $this->attribute = yii::app()->request->getParam('name');
    //$this->attribute = yii::app()->request->getParam('comments');
    $this->value = yii::app()->request->getParam('value');

    //checking params
    if (empty($this->attribute)) {
        throw new CException(Yii::t('MyCommentsTbEditableSaver.editable', 'Property "attribute" should be defined.'));
    }
    if (empty($this->primaryKey)) {
        throw new CException(Yii::t('MyCommentsTbEditableSaver.editable', 'Property "primaryKey" should be defined.'));
    }


    $model=new ProjectComments();


    $comments=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('count(project_id) as countProject')
            ->from('pm_project_comments')
            ->where("project_id = $this->primaryKey ")
            ->queryRow();

    if($comments['countProject']==0)
    {
        $model->isNewRecord=TRUE;
        $model->comments_rps=$this->value;
        $model->project_id=$this->primaryKey;

        //also set update details,added by bishal
        $model->crtd_by=Yii::app()->user->id;
        $model->crtd_dt = date('Y-m-d');
        print_r($model);die;
        $model->save();
    }

}`
```

Comment: here print($model) doesnot return any values.

Comment: Are you sure this part of code is executed?

Comment: yes i run this code in debug mode also.but didn't return any result.